# nodejs mocha - not able to test promises with stubs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, es6-promise, sinon

I am trying to unit test promises with mocha, however, I am having two issues while testing promises.

1) I am having `Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.`

2) my `requestStub` behavior is not restored or cleared after 1st test which means 2nd test is still depending on first behavior.

**handler.js**

```
"use strict";

var request = require('request');

class Handler {
    constructor() {};

    getMarketData(symbol) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            request("https://api.binance.com/api/v1/klines?symbol=" + symbol + "BTC&interval=1h", 
                function(err, res, body) {
                    if (err) {
                        return reject(err);
                    }
                    return resolve(JSON.parse(body));
            });
        });
    }
}

module.exports = Handler;
```

**handler-test.js**

```
"use strict";

var assert = require('assert');
var sinon = require('sinon');
var proxyquire = require('proxyquire').noCallThru();

describe("Handler", function() {
    var handlerInstance;
    var requestStub;

    before(function() {
        requestStub = sinon.stub();
        var Handler = proxyquire("./handler.js", {"request": requestStub});
        handlerInstance = new Handler();
    });

    afterEach(function() {
        requestStub.restore;
    });

    describe("#getMarketData", function() {
        it("test 1", function() {
            var promise = handlerInstance.getMarketData("VTC");
            requestStub.withArgs(sinon.match.any, sinon.match.any).yields(null, null, JSON.stringify({symbol: "VTC"}));
            return promise.then(function(data) {
                assert.equals(data.symbol, "VTC");
            });
        });

        it("test 2", function() {
            var promise = handlerInstance.getMarketData("STRAT");
            requestStub.withArgs(sinon.match.any, sinon.match.any).yields(null, null, JSON.stringify({symbol: "STRAT"}));
            return promise.then(function(data) {
                assert.equal(data.symbol, "STRAT");
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the behaviour of `requestStub` before you call `getMarketData()`.

At the moment when you call `request()` inside `getMarketData()` it doesn't have anything to do. So your callback never gets called, and the test timesout.

Comment: whops my bad :)